# Unable to understand object method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

Im learning JS from Codecademy right now im in Object Method section in this section we were asked to change the age of **Susan**. 
Here is the code

```
 // Change Age Function
var setAge = function (newAge) {
  this.age = newAge;
};
// New Object Bob.
var bob = new Object();
bob.age = 30;

// New Object Susan.
var susan = new Object();
susan.age = 25;

// Changing Susan Age.
susan.setAge = setAge;
susan.setAge(35);

console.log(susan.age); // Output is 35.
```

So now my question is what does this do:

```
susan.setAge = setAge;
```

and why can't i simply write

```
susan.setAge(35);
```

Here is one more code, in this code we have to change the Height and Width of the rectangle.

```
//declaring new object rectangle
var rectangle = new Object();
rectangle.height = 3;
rectangle.width = 4;

// change height function
rectangle.setHeight = function (newHeight) {
  this.height = newHeight;
};

// Change width function
rectangle.setWidth = function(newWidth){
    this.width = newWidth ; 
}

// changing Height and Width
rectangle.setHeight(6);
rectangle.setWidth(8);

console.log(rectangle.height + " " + rectangle.width); //output is 6  8
```

In above code i was able to get the answer without any error even though i didn't wrote

```
rectangle.setHeight = setHeight;         
rectangle.setWidth = setWidth;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inorder to make the line `susan.setAge(35);` work, you need `setAge()` function in `susan` object right ?

```
susan.setAge = setAge;
```

If you look close on top, you declared the function

```
 // Change Age Function
var setAge = function (newAge) {
  this.age = newAge;
};
```

now you setting that function to the object `susan` with same name  `susan.setAge`

**Update:**

```
susan.setAge = setAge;
```

as same as

```
susan.setAge = function (newAge) {
  this.age = newAge;
};;
```

That is the reason , in your other example you need not to write that line because you are directly assigning the function as shown in update.

Comment: But in my other example i didnt had to put 
 'rectangle.setHeight = setHeight';
'rectangle.setWidth = setWidth';

Comment: @AyushKatoch Updated the answer. All you doing is assigning your function to a variable and using it later. In second case ,you are directly assigning

Comment: Got it Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In general remember--setters make your object mutable, a bad idea. getters violate "Tell an object what to do, don't ask it for information and manipulate it yourself". So in general, don't add setters and getters by default. You will need them, often, but you should always find a real need before you add them. In particular setters should almost never be used in production code (Strive for immutability wherever possible, and when mutation is needed you should ask it to mutate for you, not set a value